# Column count for particular sheet

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function getMaxColumnCount() As Long

         Dim lColumn As Long, sh As Worksheet
         Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        lColumn = sh.Cells(6, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        getMaxColumnCount = lColumn

End Function
```

in my sheet1 , my data started by row number 6 and column number 2 and ends up with column number 25.
Using above function , it returns maximum column count as 25

Now i one scenrio like there are two sets of data

In Same Sheet only two sets of data
frist set of data (6,2) to (6,25) 
 second set of data starts from (6,30) to (6,50) for that  i want output as 20 for that using above code what change should i do

Comment: `sh.Cells(6, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column` will give you 50

Comment: So just to be clear, if your first set of data has 23 columns and 2nd set has 20 columns and lets say there is a 3rd set which has 5 columns then you want `5` as an answer? Also will all set have at least one blank cell in betwen?

Comment: @Siddharth Rout  yes it is like that only

Comment: posted an answer. you may have to refresh the page to see it

Answer (score 2):

> So just to be clear, if your first set of data has 23 columns and 2nd set has 20 columns and lets say there is a 3rd set which has 5 columns then you want 5 as an answer? Also will all set have at least one blank cell in betwen? – Siddharth Rout 5 mins ago     Edit
>
> @Siddharth Rout yes it is like that only – uservba12 2 mins ago

Is this what you are trying?

**Logic**: Get the last column and then find the blank cell before that. Subtract to get column count.

**Code**:

```
Option Explicit

Function GetLastSetColumnCount() As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim BlankCol As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = Activesheet '~~> OR relevant sheet
    
    With ws
        lCol = .Cells(6, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        For i = lCol To 1 Step -1
            If Len(Trim(.Cells(6, i).Value)) = 0 Then
                BlankCol = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
    GetLastSetColumnCount = lCol - BlankCol
End Function
```